# How to add content in csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x

so I am looking to add details of wifi available in my surroundings. and I am getting like this output so how can I store it in csv file so I can use them later. Here is the code and output I tried some random stuff

```
import subprocess
import platform
import time

identify = platform.system()

print(f"Your Operating Platform Is {identify}")



if identify == "Windows":
    cmd = ["netsh", "wlan", "show", "networks", "mode=BSSID"]
    networks = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, errors = networks.communicate()
    data = output.decode("utf-8")
    file = open("output.txt", "a")
    file.write(data)
    file.close()
    print(data)
    data.strip()
    f = open("output.txt", "r")
    read = f.read()
    read.strip()
    if data == read:
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")

    f.close()

elif identify == "Linux":
    cmd = ["nmcli", "-f",  "SSID,BSSID,ACTIVE", "dev", "wifi", "list"] 
    networks = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, errors = networks.communicate()
    print(output.decode("utf-8"))
    data = output.decode("utf-8") 
    print(data)

else:
    print("Unsupported For Your Operating System/\.")
```

```
There are 1 networks currently visible.

SSID 1 : Jiofi
    Network type            : Infrastructure
    Authentication          : WPA2-Personal
    Encryption              : CCMP
    BSSID 1                 : c0:61:75:db:d1:08
         Signal             : 100%
         Radio type         : 652.11n
         Channel            : 6
         Basic rates (Mbps) : 1 2 5.4 54
         Other rates (Mbps) : 6 9 12 87 24 36 30 54
```

Comment: How are you planning on that `.csv` file to look like? CSV is for table-like data and here you have 2 rows, then a dictionary with sub-dictionaries. Some more clarification will be helpful (maybe even provide a sample screenshot of expected result).

Comment: @OmerM25 sample is in my quaetion I cant really give screenshot cause it has details of my wifi, can you suugest some better options plz with code

Comment: Please show an example how you would the CSV file to look like.

Comment: This boils down to "Code this for me" - no attempt at storing/parsing anything was shown. Please read [ask] and provide a [mre]  that showcases your attempt and problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
s = """Interface name : Wi-Fi
There are 1 networks currently visible.

SSID 1 : Jiofi
    Network type            : Infrastructure
    Authentication          : WPA2-Personal
    Encryption              : CCMP
    BSSID 1                 : c0:61:75:db:d1:08
         Signal             : 100%
         Radio type         : 652.11n
         Channel            : 6
         Basic rates (Mbps) : 1 2 5.4 54
         Other rates (Mbps) : 6 9 12 87 24 36 30 54"""
         
         
s = s.split("\n")
with open("output.csv", "w+") as file:
    file.write("header1,header2" + "\n")
    for elem in s:
        row = elem.split(":")
        if len(row) < 2:
            continue
        line = ""
        for i in range(len(row)):
            row[i] = row[i].strip()
            line += row[i] + ","
        file.write(line[:-1] +  "\n")
```

Comment: This looks like a good implementaiton, but the code fails here `file.writeline(line[:-1])` throwing the following error: `'_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'writeline'`

Comment: Weird. Should be fixed?

Comment: produces a file, but the top row should be the headers and the next rows are the data (in order to be csv like).

Comment: How about this? Replace "header1,header2" with your actual header names, whatever you want them to be (you didn't specify in the question, at least at time of writing).

Answer (score 0):

You can write to CSV in a number of ways `csv`, `pandas` or even just write a text file using the `with open('newfile.csv', 'a') as f:` command.

The key with the data that you have provided is to use everything before the `:` as headers and everything after the `:` as the values.

For determining where the `:` are you would probably ise the regular expressions module `import re`.

both the headers and values are separated by commas to be `csv` (comma separated) format.

If you have an example of what you have tried so far, this would be useful.

Comment: I added code for it

Comment: two comments on the code.   [1] it is always better to use the `with` statement for opening and closing files.  [2]  Please add the code that you have done so far for dealing with the write files (ie. where you are stuck & what you have already tried).

Comment: Bah this it only the code the real problem is first i was using txt file now I want to use csv file cause if a wifi detail is alreay in csv file it should not append the output

Answer (score 0):

- Remove the second and third line.
- Then in pass 1, isolate every string in the first column, trim and concatenate resulting terms into a header line, delimit each term with semicolon ; or comma ,
- Then, on a new output line, concatenate your data in the second column and delimit each term with semicolon ; or comma ,

The result will be a single textfile containing 2 lines, that can be pasted into Excel using Control-V, then Tab Data, Text To Columns. Use the delimiter you have selected.

Keep in mind your strings may *not* contain the delimiter you choose. If they do, you will be required to use double quotes around your data in the content line.

Comment: I didnt understand a thing can you give me some code

Comment: No time for that. And SO is not a code factory. I clearly explained how to make a valid CSV.

Comment: i will add the correct code here later (or another can add as an edit to the post), but @ezra looks quite close (aside from formatting rows).

Comment: @D.L Hijacking somebody else's answer by editing it into a different answer is not acceptable here. Post an answer of your own instead if you like.

Comment: [1] I referenced the person @ezra as there is little point replicating an already good answer. [2] i posted the output that the code yields... nevertheless, your point is accepted and next time i will edit *my own* response as it is clearer to do this.